# function to mapping array element for an object array

Tags: javascript, arrays

i am having trouble getting a function to map array elements from another array. I have three arrays of states with city names and another zip_codes array that contains [{city: "City 1", zip: "11111"},{city: "City 2", zip: "22222"} ...]. There are no spelling errors in city names all arrays. However, when I ran the storeState function which maps the zip codes the stores the cities into a new "states" array, it is only picking up some of the cities.

Is there anything wrong with my codes that is causing it to skip some of the cities? BTW, I am new to JavaScript.

---

```
function mapZip(city){
for (i = 0; i < zip_codes.length; ++i)
    if(zip_codes[i].City == city) return zip_codes[i].zip;
}

    var states =[];
function storeState(state,stateLong){
  for(i = 0; i < state.length; ++i){
    states.push({
      state: stateLong, 
      city: state[i], 
      zip: mapZip(state[i])
    })
  }  
}

storeState(CO,"Colorado")
storeState(CA,"California")
storeState(ID,"Idaho")

console.log(states)
```

Comment: Do you have to use `[{city:"city1",zip:"zip1"}...]` instead of just `{"city1":"zip1","city2":"zip2"}`?

Comment: Your question is a little unclear. Can you clarify what you want the final data structure to look like?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you didn't use the i index as it should be.
you have to use it with **var**. otherwise it is a **global variable**.

```
   function mapZip(city){
for (var i = 0; i < zip_codes.length; ++i)
    if(zip_codes[i].City == city) return zip_codes[i].zip;
}

    var states =[];
function storeState(state,stateLong){
  for(var i = 0; i < state.length; ++i){
    states.push({
      state: stateLong, 
      city: state[i], 
      zip: mapZip(state[i])
    })
  }  
}

storeState(CO,"Colorado")
storeState(CA,"California")
storeState(ID,"Idaho")

console.log(states)
```

Comment: Thank you! A quick fix to var j in function mapZip() produces the right answer.

Comment: you dont have to change the variable to j. you can put it i. but in any case you must put var before the variable.

Comment: If the problem was solved mark the question as answered